# jQuery (content slider) not working in WordPress template

Tags: jquery, wordpress, slider, conflict

## The problem

I've added a jQuery content slider (Coda Slider 2.0) to my Wordpress template page but it breaks (only the text "loading" appears).

## Demos

I've provided live examples here to see my code in action:

[Broken slider](http://www.directsponsor.org/) | [Working Slider](http://www.directsponsor.org/wp-content/themes/directsponsor/js/coda-slider/)

## What I've tried

I've tried substituting the dollar sign for "jQuery" in my templates head but to no avail.

```
<!--Slider-->
<!-- Begin Stylesheets -->
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') ?>/js/coda-slider/stylesheets/reset.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />-->
            <!--Commented out because it's already called previously.-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') ?>/js/coda-slider/stylesheets/coda-slider-2.0.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<!-- End Stylesheets -->

<!-- Begin JavaScript -->
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') ?>/js/coda-slider/javascripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') ?>/js/coda-slider/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') ?>/js/coda-slider/javascripts/jquery.coda-slider-2.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery().ready(function() {
            jQuery('#coda-slider-1').codaSlider(
            {autoSlide: true, 
            autoHeight: false, 
            autoSlideStopWhenClicked: true, 
            autoSlideInterval:4000,
            dynamicArrows: false,
            dynamicTabs: false}
            );
        });
     </script>
<!-- End JavaScript -->
```

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) with Firefox, or in Chrome or Safari or IE8, use the developer tools to check for JS errors on demo that doesn't work. Right now, the JS easing library isn't loading because of a 404.

Comment: Thanks. I used Chrome to debug and found the 404 you mentioned. Sure enough, my path to the easing library was missing a directory.

Answer (score 0):

You are targeting `coda-slider-1`, but your container div is `coda-slider-wrapper` (unless I'm missing something obvious here). This would definitely mess things up. Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('div#coda-slider-wrapper').codaSlider(
            {...
            );
        });
```

(unrelated) You might also consider pushing your behaviors into an external js document. Also, the preferred method of inserting javascript is through `wp_enqueue_scripts`, which you do an add_action to in your `functions.php.` Just a thought ;)

@markratledge is definitely right, additionally - `404 not found error`. Firebug is your friend.

**update**
To ensure the correct insertion of javascript into the header, wordpress first registers and then enqueues any required scripts. *The correct way* to insert custom scripts is to `add_action` to wp's built in methods. Inserting scripts manually will work, but there is a chance you may interfere with any native script embeds. At any rate: this is an example for the thickbox jquery plugin, and is generic enough to use for any js. You can add this to your theme's `functions.php` script, or to a custom plugin, or whatever your case may be.

```
// register scripts 
if (! function_exists(thickbox_register){
function thickbox_register() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery','http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js');
    wp_register_script( 'thickbox', 'path to thickbox'.thickbox.js, 'jquery');
    }  
}   
add_action('init', 'thickbox_register');

//print the now registered scripts 
if (! function_exists(thickbox_enqueue){
function thickbox_enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'thickbox' );
    }  
}
add_action('wp_print_scripts', 'thickbox_enqueue');
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion though I've double checked it and coda-slider-1 is indeed meant to be targeted. See here: http://www.ndoherty.biz/demos/coda-slider/2.0/#example4

Comment: I'm happy to use your suggestion regarding wp_enqueue_scripts but can you explain the benefit in brief?

Comment: well - looks like you got it working out. What was the issue?

Answer (score 0):

try it this way

```
$(function(){
         $('#coda-slider-1').codaSlider({
                autoSlide: true, 
                autoHeight: false, 
                autoSlideStopWhenClicked: true, 
                autoSlideInterval:4000,
                dynamicArrows: false,
                dynamicTabs: false
         });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Though this wasn't the root of the issue it is a very useful way of avoiding conflicting dollar signs.